How to automatically reset cached tiles after layers were changed?
I have a requirement to use GWC to optimize WMS tile devilering. So, I don't have any problems plugging it in, but I can't find any information about reseting cache after geometry data or styles of the layer were changed. 
So, in general, I want to reset GWC tile cache automatically, not manually:)

GeoServer will automatically clear the cache if the style changes and I think it does the same for geometry changes but I can't be sure. If it doesn't then you can call the rest API with the bounding box of your features to force a cache clear.

It seems to me I found nessesery information (link above).
https://docs.geoserver.org/2.19.x/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/defaults.html 
In the cache defaults setting, we can configure reset cache policies:)

I tried this with styles and then I'll try with layer chema's changes))))
